# How to control the positions of multiple captions under images?

Tags: spacing, captions, positioning

I am new to latex and want to make good format pictures with captions, like this [one](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/%7Eforo0012/FDSG/FD_smoke_guiding.pdf).

[image]

After some search, I was able to generate similar captions with

```
 \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
            \includegraphics{figure1.pdf} 
            \begin{center} figure1 \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
            \includegraphics{figure2.pdf}
            \begin{center} figure2 \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{figure1 vs. figure2 }
  \end{figure}
```

However, there is a large space between the text.
In general, how can I have more control over the position of text?

Comment: See also \subfloat from subcaption.  It fits the caption to the width of the contents.  Or you can do it yourself with a savebox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all kinds of options here, the simplest of which is to set the "sub-figure" construction inside a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \mbox{}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a} \\
    figure1
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=7em]{example-image-b} \\
    figure2
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \mbox{}
  \caption{figure1 vs. figure2}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Since you're using `tabular`, just change the space by adding an optional `<len>` argument to the `tabular` line break `\\[<len>]`. If you have multi-line "sub-figure" captions, then one could figure out something different:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \mbox{}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \makebox[12em]{\includegraphics[width=7em]{example-image-b}}\hfill
  \mbox{}\par
  %\vspace{<len>} to increase the space
  \mbox{}\hfill
  \makebox[5em]{figure1}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{12em}@{}}
    This is a beautiful figure that needs more descriptive words
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \mbox{}
  \caption{figure1 vs. figure2}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Of course, in a general setting, I'd recommend using [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption); you should find sufficient examples within the [`subcaption` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `subigure` defined in the `subcaption` package and write text belos images with `\caption*{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\captionsetup{skip=1ex, font=small}
\captionsetup[sub]{skip=-1ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a} \\
    \caption*{figure 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B} \\
    \caption*{figure 2}
\end{subfigure}%
  \caption{figure1 vs. figure2}
  \label{fig:comparison}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```